# c - fork - which will survive xor conditions

Tags: c

I have this c program and need to calculate how many '1' will be printed.

*assume that each new process get unique id

```
int main() {
  if(logicalXor(fork(), fork()){
     exit
  }
  if(bitwiseXor(fork(), fork()){
     print("1"; 
     exists()
  }
}
```

after the first `if` we left with 2 process.

inside this second `if`, each of them "become" 4 . so we have 8 right now:

```
00 -> wont survive the second if
01 -> survive
10 -> survive
11 
00 -> wont survive
01 -> survive
10 -> survive
11
(1 present some id that is not 0)
```

I have 2 question:

1. am i thinking about it right?
2. I'm not sure about the case of '11' in the bitwiseXor. it can be either true or false. the condition `a&b` may be 0 or not. for example: `101 & 010` = 0 but `110 & 100 = 100`

```
logicalXor(int x, int y) {return (a||b) && !(a&&b)}
bitwiseXor(int x, int y) {return (a|b) & ~(a&b)}
```

Comment: What is a "logical XOR"? What does the two "XOR" functions actually do? And remember that `fork` returns either `0` or the PID of the new process (which can never be `1`), and that PIDs doesn't have any relationship (two consecutive calls to `fork` might not return consecutive PID's). Lastly, if you want to show a program to us, please make sure it's a [mcve], which doesn't have any unrelated errors in it.

Comment: `fork()` can fail and return `-1` ("*true*") without creating a new process

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I imagine they do `(a?1:0) ^ (b?1:0)` and `a ^ b` respectively

Answer (score 0):

In the child, `fork` return zero. On a two's-complement machine, each bit of zero is zero.

In the parent, `fork` returns a value that's neither zero nor -1. On a two's-complement machine, that means at least one of the bits is zero, and at least one of the bits is one.

---

Just before `logicalXor` is called, you end up with four processes:

```
|
|
|\________________fork_________________
|                                      \
| !=0,!=1                              | =0
|                                      |
|                                      |                    
|                                      |                    
|\______fork______                     |\______fork______   
|                 \                    |                 \  
| !=0,!=-1         | =0                | !=0,!=-1         | =0
|                  |                   |                  |
```

Some of these will exit. Some will continue. How many will survive?

---

Each of he surviving processes will become four just like we saw above.

For each of the surviving process, some will print `1`. How many?

Multiplying this number by the number of surviving processes will tell you how many `1` are printed.

---

Note: The above assumes that none of the calls to `fork` returns an error.

Note: The order in which the arguments (calls to `fork`) are evaluated is unspecified, but ultimately irrelevant to us.